# How to use callback in a loop

Tags: node.js, callback

In the code below I am getting n number of values in from a function and I want to set them in the array and return callback

```
if(code=='ok'){
  let arrl = idArr.map(obj =>{
      array[0].userId = obj;
      return array[0]
  })
  console.log("arrl",arrl)
  return callback('ok',arrl)  
}
else{
  return callback('error',"please check")
}
```

But if I use it inside the map function it will return error as client can be called once and if I am returning it outside it sending same data
please someone can help it will be a great help

Comment: If possible to give an example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the value in a state variable and then call your callback function using useEffect() in functional or component did mount in class component.